# Do I have to roll multiple shooting dice individually?

Tags: savage-worlds, shooting

When I get multiple shooting dice for one action, e.g. due high Rate of Fire, Fanning or using double shotguns, do I have to assign each individual die to a specific target before the roll, effectively rolling them individually (or having the need for different colors to assign), or can I roll them all at once and decide after the result which one affects which target? Do I resolve one die before rolling the next, so do I have to gamble when it is the best time to use the wild die as replacement, or do I first roll all dice (if necessary keeping track which die goes to which target), and then pick the one I want to upgrade with the wild die?

Or is it sufficient to declare the targets of the shot, but assign the actual dice after they are rolled as a pool together with the wild die?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you take an action with multiple attacks **that occur as part of a single Action** such as using a weapon with a rate of fire of greater than one, fire multiple bolts, using Frenzy or Fanning the Hammer you take the following steps.

- Declare the targets you are firing at
- Roll a number of Shooting/Fighting/Spellcasting
  dice equal to the number of attacks along a with a single Wild Die.
  For example if you were firing a weapon with ROF 3 and you had d8
  Shooting you would roll 3d8 and a d6 for your Wild Die
- You then choose which results to assign to each of your targets. Continuing the
  previous example, lets say you ended up with only 1 successful hit
  and you had declared two targets. This means you can choose which of
  the two targets is hit.

For confirmation of this process see [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42547&highlight=bolt%20wild%20die), [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30841&highlight=frenzy) and [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37403&highlight=rof%20attacks).
For confirmation that you wait until after you have rolled your dice before assigning 'hits, see [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31216&highlight=choose%20target).

When you resolve attacks during the same round **that occur as part of different actions**, such as firing once with a gun in your left hand and once with a gun in your right hand, you resolve the attacks completely separately, each with their own Wild Die.

Comment: Thanks again for the references. However (maybe I am to tired today) I can't see how those address/proove the issue "when do I assign SDs to targets". Reading other posts, I would assume that the order described here is correct (declare attack-amount per target, roll, switch WD, assign dice to attacks), but for now I neither can't find or imply it from the rules or an FAQ/Errata/offical forum...

Comment: @TeXter I've added a reference that clarifies that particular part. Is that any better?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example:

RoF 3
You take 3 shooting die and 1 wild die

If you assign them before or after rolling them is a question for your GM.

Answer (score -1):

My interpretation of the example related to the RoF is that you have to decide which shot aims at which target before rolling, but you can decide to replace any of the normal rolls with the wild card die after the fact.

So, assign your targets, roll your RoF number of shooting dice (either in sequence or with colored dice) and then decide which of the rolls the wild card should replace, if any.

> The player decides to put two shots into the closest terrorist and one at the further target. He rolls the two at the closest terrorist first, then rolls a third d8 for the second. He also rolls his Wild Die.

Everything else doesn't make much sense to me - every roll represents one projectile and you have to aim the weapon at the target before shooting...